# WPF ComboBox MVVM DataBinding Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have the following classes (I will keep this simple. Please assume I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged):

```
AddMovieViewModel 
{ 
   public Movie NewMovie {get;set;}

   public ObservableCollection<Language> LanguageList {get;set;}
}

Movie
{
   public Language MovieLanguage {get;set;}
}

Langauge
{
   public int LanguageID {get;set;}
   public string LanguageName {get;set;}
}
```

Now I have a View(DataContext bound to AddMovieViewModel) containing the following ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding LanguageList}" Style="{x:Null}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="LanguageName" 
                      SelectedValuePath="LanguageID" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding NewMovie.MovieLanguage, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding NewMovie.MovieLanguage.LanguageID, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Requirement : Suppose I have a AddMovieViewModel.LanguageList having LanguageID's from 1 to 5. The program will first fetch a default Language Id from the DB - assume it to be 2. This LanguageID belongs to the NewMovie object, i.e., NewMovie will have its MovieLanguage property set to a Language object whose LanguageID value is 2. Now the ComboBox should be displaying the Language item corresponding to LanguageID = 2. Hope this is not confusing.

Problem : I would want to know, do I have to retrieve the relevant Language object(having LanguageID=2) from LanguageList of view model and then set it to the NewMovie.MovieLanguage property, like this:

```
NewMovie.MovieLanguage = LanguageList.First(lang => lang.LanguageID == 2);
```

or is there any better alternate to achieve this without using the Linq syntax ? It this the right approach ? Is it necessary that the NewMovie.MovieLanguage object should be from the LanguageList collection for the ComboBox to be shown as SelectedItem ? Does the Binding perform some hash checks or does it try to match the LanguageID values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combobox uses *object.Equals* to show an item from *ItemsSource* when *SelectedItem* property has been updated, so you have several ways to achieve the desired behavior:

1. Use a reference from a collection. Actually, it is your example with Linq.
2. Override Equals method in Language class.
3. Use SelectedIndex property